# How do i get negative timestamp to save in firebase - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Searched everywhere but could not found any solution or answer. I can get timestamp using following code:

```
var timestamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

But I want to store negative timestamp for sorting purposes. How do I get it?

When I try to multiply it with **-1** it gives NaN error because it's an object. How?

Comment: Why do you need to set a negative timestamp? I don't think its good practice to modify the Timestamp, as they're deliberately difficult to access and represent a value used for internal calculations. If what you need is to prioritize certain elements, why not use the priority feature? Or add a field to sort by that isn't timestamp?

Comment: @TheCog A common reason developers may want this is to get the results in descending order of timestamp. All ordered Firebase Database queries return results in ascending order, so if you want to show them in descending order you either need to reverse client-side or keep an inverted property.

Comment: Why not take your array of results and just reverse it then? array.reverse() should do the trick. I didn't realize that firebase doesn't have a way to reverse the return order, so i can see why you'd want to do this, i'm still not sure its the right way of solving the issue.

Comment: I have a full example of negative timestamps in Angular, but the design pattern should be helpful even if using a different framework: https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/negative-timestamps-to-sort-records-in-firebase/

Comment: @TheCog19, But if you want to do Pagination, array.reverse only works for the batch that you grabbed e.g. 5-10 images/videos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negative timestamps are useful when the dataset is too large to reverse client-side.

The Firebase server timestamp is an object that gets converted to a number after the data is saved. Therefore, you need to save the postive timestamp, then convert it to a negative timestamp after the initial push. Here is a verified working example.

```
  let timestamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
  const promise = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push({ timestamp })
  const key = promise.key

  promise.then(_ => {
    const postRef = firebase.database().ref('/posts/' + key)
    postRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      timestamp = snapshot.val().timestamp * -1
      postRef.update({ timestamp })
    });
  })
```

Comment: Thanks great. solution